# Can I use metrics from one application to automatically scale a different one?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, horizontal-scaling

I currently have a service running in my kubernetes cluster which exports my metrics to prometheus which is monitoring my cluster and services.

I want to use a metric from this service to automatically scale (hpa) a second service based on these metrics.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to make it work!

You can choose the scale target in one parameter and under the metrics section choose the target of a different service.

Example yaml

```
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
metadata:
  name: my-app-hpa
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: my-app
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
  - type: Object
    object:
      target:
        kind: Service
        name: app-that-generates-metrics
      metricName: my-metric
      targetValue: 10
```

Comment: Was the metric a ```cpu```/```memory``` or ```network``` or a total custom value from the ```app-that-generates-metrics```?

Comment: A custom value from the app

Answer (score 1):

I never tested what you want to do, but here you have a tutorial on how to scale a pod with custom metrics: https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-autoscaling-custom-metrics/

You may have some tweeking to do to use a metric from a pod to scale another, but I hope it helps.

Comment: I'll give it a try and see if the hpa yaml can refer to a different service

Comment: for some reason in the tutorial you sent the hpa doesn't recognize the amount of current http requests even though prometheus is collecting it

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the fact that you are using a different pod? So the metric doesn't apply to your hpa?

Answer (score 0):

To start work with `custom HPA` you need install on cluster some things:

1. Enable [Kubernetes Aggregator Layer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/configure-aggregation-layer/)
2. Start using [metrics-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server) (instead heapster);